# Can I regenerate .designer.cs based on a manually edited .dbml?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, database-design, linq-to-sql

I've made some modifications (renamings mostly) in a DBML file manually (using a text editor). Can I use VisualStudio to recreate the .designer.cs file based on new DBML?

Comment: Just hitting "save" should be enough, but otherwise Muhammad is correct - you can re-invoke it manually

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Right click on your dbml file and select "Run Custom Tool"